# How to get to the object inside the border

Tags: c#, wpf

I have grid1 which contains a set of borders, every border contain one label.

XAML SAMPLE

```
<grid1>
  <border>
    <label />
  </border>
  <border>
    <label />
  </border>
</grid1>
```

Im trying to loop trought the labels but i cant get accest to them.

```
foreach(var item in grid1.Children)
{

}
```

This loop returns only border as a child, but i have to go deeper and dont know how.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the border's [Child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child.aspx):

```
foreach(var item in grid1.Children)
{
     Label label = null;
     var border = item as Decorator;
     if (border != null)
          label = border.Child as Label;

     if (label != null)
     {
         // The label will be here...
     }
}
```

Note that, if you provide names for your labels, you could just call [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) to directly find each label.